# My Win7 is waging a passive war against mice

Tags: windows-7, mouse, freeze

I apologize for the vague title; truth is, the more I try to fix this computer, the less I understand *what* exactly is wrong with it.

There is a quick recap at the end, this is mostly to show what I've tried so far.

---

We have a computer at work for simulations. It runs Windows 7, 64-bit. And although it technically functions, there are a few things that are very wrong with it.

First off, the mouse pointer has a tiny bit of lag between the moment the mouse is moved and the moment it moves on screen; it's also rather sluggish, and will refuse to move more than an inch per second sometimes. Even worse if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is held; the mouse becomes a figurative slug. Oh and also the scroll wheel doesn't work (but the scroll button does). This is not a problem with the mouse itself; I have tried in on my laptop, no issue there. Other mice work just as badly on this computer.

I have tried to access the Wheel tab of the Mouse settings, but it's not there. If I try to access the details of the mouse, the system freezes. I have managed to re-install the driver once, with no change observed.

After much google-fu, I have determined it could be something to do with the display; that correlated with some ATIeRecord errors I have in the Log Viewer. The graphic card used is an AMD Firepro W4100; I have re-installed the drivers to be sure, no change. To note: trying to run the AMD Cleanup Utility invariably results in the system freezing, whether I'm using the card or if I'm plugged directly on the Intel chipset. I had to use Display Driver Uninstaller to make a clean re-install. The errors are still there, too. I'm beginning to think there's something wrong deeper.

I have tested the HDD with chkdsk, Crystaldisk and Tune HD Pro, no sign of error from that as far as I can tell (I haven't tried SeaTools yet).

The Memory Diagnostic Tool did not find anything suspicious either.

IntelProcessor Diagnostic Tool seemed content as well. Not sure if it diagnosed the motherboard though.

There *might* be an issue with the PSU; sometimes, when I restart the computer, or simply when I boot it after a few hours, it *starts* to boot but stops and powers off after a few seconds. Booting it again afterwards works just fine; it never did that twice in a row so far.

---

So in short:

- The mouse is sluggish, and the scroll wheel doesn't work (but the button does).
- The system sometimes freezes when I try to access some details, or when I open something related to drivers (AFAIK). It *has* happened to freeze for no observable reason once or twice.
- Minor occasional boot issue; Windows doesn't even detect it as a Bad Shutdown.

Specs:

OS: Windows 7 Pro x64, pre-installed by Dell.

CPU: Intel Core i5-6500 @ 3.2GHz

RAM: 1x8GB

GPU: AMD FirePro W4100

---

Initially, I just wanted to fix the mouse, but I think **the freezing issue is quite worrying. There are many things that could cause this; any idea where to start looking?**

Note: I *have* the option to nuke the whole thing and install a clean OS upon the ashes of it, but I'd like to understand the issue before I cleanse it.

Comment: Sounds like your USB ports and/or drivers are junk - it's the only point of commonality with your keyboard, mouse, and shutdown.  Have you attempted to update the chipset drivers or use a generic USB driver to possibly repair them?

Comment: If you suspect the PSU, might be the cause of the problems, then you should replace it.  Create an image of the system, nuke the system, install and patch the operating system and verify the problem still exists.  If it does then you have a hardware problem, likely connected to your motherboard, because I assume your using a USB mouse.  You will need to try these suggestions before an answer can be provided.  Its also possible the problem is caused by I/O problems, so if it still exists after you install Windows again, replace the HDD.

Comment: Sounds fair. I am currently cleaning the drivers. If that does nothing, I'll nuke. It might take some time though, I have more urgent projects to work on, this week.